# R shiny slider doesn't appear

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a slider input and make a scatterplot whose number of points are the same as the slider input.

I wrote this code in R Script.

```
library(shiny)

ui= basicPage(
  sliderInput('n', 'Number of points:',
              min=10, max=500, value=100),
  plotOutput('distPlot')
)

server= function(input,output) {
  output$distPlot = renderPlot ({
    plot(rnorm(input$n) , rnorm(input$n))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

An easy code. But I run the app, there doesn't appear a slider.

The only thing appearing is

"Number of points:" and a rectangle.

Even if I put a number in the rectangle and press 'Enter', nothing happens.

There is no problem with the code but maybe I am addressing the shiny app in a wrong way.

Both the version of Rstudio and Shiny is the newest.

Comment: It works fine for me once I correct your typo of `surver=` to `server=`.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't think I made a typo

Comment: But still, a slider doesn't appear without an error message

Comment: (1) If you get a mention, include it verbatim. (2) I say again: once I change `surver=` to `server=`, it works, including that I can see the slider. If it matters, R-3.5.3, shiny-1.3.2 (I don't think it does).

Comment: Perhaps you have a stale `ui` and `server` hanging around? Try removing `ui` and `server` (and even `surver`), redefine them, and try again.

Comment: Did you run it in R script?

Comment: Yes the version is R3.5.3 and shiny 1.3.2

Comment: No, and while I see that you mentioned it in your question, I think it wasn't clear you were trying to execute a shiny app with `rscript.exe` (or the mac/linux equivalent). Perhaps you can edit your question to be more clear about that?

Comment: If you look at the source, they are identical. But if you look at the browser's developer/debugging console, you'll see errors such as `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:3427/shared/jquery.min.js”`, which to me suggests that there is something in the `shiny` environment that is not properly supported in `Rscript` itself. You may need to open a [new issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/) ... wait, [rstudio/shiny#1376](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1376) was opened and forgotten about by the asker, then closed.

Comment: (and by "source" I mean "html source" that the browser sees)